# How to fix the JMeter script recording error?

Tags: performance, proxy, jmeter, dns, record

How to fix the JMeter script recording error?

When I am clicking the `Start` button the JMeter applications says:

> Could not create script recorder - see log for details: >> keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: DNSName components must consist of letters, digits, and hyphens << Command failed, code: 1

[image]

I am just trying to record the loading of [this](https://opencart.abstracta.us/) web page.

I tried going to the Windows Proxy settings and setting the address to `localhost` and port to `8080`. But it did not help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to provide a **valid** [DNS hostname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) to the Recording Template.

   To wit instead of `https://opencart.abstracta.us` you need to use just `opencart.abstracta.us`

   [image]
2. You need to use port `8888` instead of `8080` in order to reach JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder

   [image]
3. You should set the proxy settings in **browser**, not in the whole operating system. If the browser proxy settings are integrated with the operating system consider switching to a better browser which has separate proxy configuration like Firefox
4. There is an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium). In this case you won't have to worry about proxies and SSL certificates.